# Updating the state on every iteration of for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

guys!
I have a problem when going through every iteration of the `for-loop` my array variable in the state remains with 1 element. Here is my input
    `<input accept="image/*" type="file" onChange={handlePhotoChange} multiple/>`
and this is the `handlePhotoChange` method

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])
const handlePhotoChange = async (event) => {
    const { files } = event.target;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
      const file = files[i];

      if (!file.type.match('image')) {
        continue;
      }

      setImages([...images, { loading: true, src: null }]);
      await firebase.doUploadImage(file, auth.uid);
      const url = await firebase.getImageUrl(file.name, auth.uid);
      setImages([...images.slice(0, -1), { loading: false, src: url }]);
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is setting the loading variable to true before uploading the image in firebase storage and by this `loading` I show a loader. Then my upload is ready and I get the firebase url of the image and overwrite the last element in the array images[]. Then we continue with next image. This way I am going to show a loader on every single image. But the problem is that `images` array after the loop has only the last added element. I guess it is something with the `setImages` function that is async but waiting for your opinions. Thank you :)

Comment: You've misunderstood how `useState` works, `images` will always have the same value as it had when the loop was started.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly could a solution like this work:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

const handlePhotoChange = async (event) => {
    const { files } = event.target;

    setImages([...images, { loading: true, src: null }]);

    let newImagesArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
      const file = files[i];

      if (!file.type.match('image')) {
        continue;
      }

      await firebase.doUploadImage(file, auth.uid);
      const url = await firebase.getImageUrl(file.name, auth.uid);
      let obj = {loading: false, src: url};
      newImagesArray.push(obj);
    }

    //get state
    let newImages = images;
    //add new images
    newImages.push(newImagesArray)
    //update state
    setImages(newImages);
}
```

What we're doing is creating a temporary array `newImages` to hold all the new files. Then once we loop through all the uploaded files, we put the array into the state.

Let me know if it works/if there are issues.

Comment: Isn't it `setImages([...images, ...newImages]);` at the end?

Comment: @KristianKamenov I could have messed up that part, sorry. I updated the code to show how I usually handle updating array states.

Comment: In your example i will push in the state first `{ loading: true, src: null }` and then for every iteration of the loop i will push `{ loading: false, src: url }` and thats not the case. The case is when i iterate first i push `{ loading: true, src: null }` then I process the image in firebase and meanwhile I show the user a loader animation. Then when the images is processed I push `{ loading: false, src: url }` and stop the loader animation and show the uploaded image already. Then I continue with the next image and next image and so on...

Comment: @KristianKamenov can you show me what your `images` state looks like when there is data in there?

Comment: with this problem I only have 1 value in the array and it is `[{ loading: false, src: {last_processed_image_ID}}]`

Comment: @KristianKamenov Sorry I've been gone. Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is async just change state once. Also if you want access to previous state, you should use the callback version of useState

```
const [stateObject, setObjectState] = useState({
  firstKey: '',
  secondKey: '',
});

setObjectState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  secondKey: 'value',
}));
```

you could split up the loading states and uploaded states to make it easier to manage, pseudo code below

```
const handlePhotoChange = (event) => {
  const { files } = event.target;
  const loadingImages = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
    const file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.match('image')) {
      continue;
    }
    loadingImages.push({ file });

    firebase.doUploadImage(file, auth.uid)
      .then(// add to uploaded images state)
  }
  // set loading images state after iteration is complete
}
```

Comment: but in your example i will not have the `loading`. In my example i add `loading: true` before processing the image with firebase. What I want is: 1) add `loading: true` for the first image => show the loader animation; 2) process the image in firebase 3) after firebase callback is ready add the first image url in the state and set `loading: false` so the loader animation is stopped and the image is shown. 4) continue with the next image and so on...

Comment: your not using `ids` with your files, so it doesn't matter if you track loading as a count of an array size or just counting how many objects in an array have a `loading: true` value

Comment: okay, consider that I am using `{ index: i, loading: true, src: null }`